# Getting AutomationPattern array count

Tags: c#, exception, ui-automation

I have a C# application using System.Windows.Automation that recently quit working.

```
AutomationElement elm = AutomationElement.FromHandle(hwnd);
AutomationElement elmFirst = elm.FindFirst(TreeScope.Descendants,
    new PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.NameProperty, "blah"));
if (elmFirst != null)
{
    AutomationPattern[] patterns = elmFirst.GetSupportedPatterns();
    if (patterns.Length > 0)
```

the last line now gives the following exception:

Unable to cast object of type 'System.Windows.Automation.TextPattern' to type 'System.Windows.Automation.ValuePattern'.

I'm just trying to get the size of the AutomationPattern array...

Answer (score 0):

It was actually a problem with the next line:

`ValuePattern val = (ValuePattern)elmFirst.GetCurrentPattern(patterns[0]);`

It was actually a TextPattern all along, but the cast used to work?